# Hide Form1 when Form2 is displayed

Tags: c#, .net

How can i hide Form1 while Form2 is displayed?.
I have tried this but it does not Hide Form1 when clicking the Button

```cs
        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 scriptHub = new Form2();
            scriptHub.Show();
            Form1 mainScreen = new Form1();
            mainScreen.Hide();
        }
```

Comment: you are hiding a newly created instance of the mainScreen. Use the original instance instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a new Forms and hidding it quick after... You have to acces your current form. Use the Keyword "this":

---

```
this.Hide();
```

---

Your code should look like this:

---

```
 private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 scriptHub = new Form2();
        scriptHub.Show();
        this.Hide(); //Hide your mainscreen
    }
```

---

Dont forget that you are hidding the forms and not closing it that means that your CPU will be more busy than if you colse it. Hope it helps

Comment: oh well did not knew that ty

Comment: You are welcome ! If you need a detalied explanation let me know ! Dont forget to mark the question as the solution to your problem if it helped

Comment: Side note: `Hide();` (instead of `this.Hide();`) will be enough

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Yes of corse, thank you. I like to use "this" so the code looks clear for me. But I think it's a matter of taste. Thanks